# Proving an integral is finite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, estimation, bessel-functions

I have the following integral:

$$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{J_{1}(|\alpha|)J_{1}(|k- \alpha|)}{|\alpha||k-\alpha|} \ \mathrm{d}\alpha \right)^2 \ \mathrm{d}k,$$

where both $\alpha$ and $k$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $k \neq 0$, and $J_{\nu}$ denotes the Bessel function of the first kind. I'm having some trouble with the best way to approach this integral. If we focus on the inner integral first, then using the fact that for sufficiently large, positive $z$ we have $|J_{\nu}(z)| \leqslant C|z|^{-1/2},$ then the inner integral can be reduced to

$$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\alpha|^{-3/2}|k-\alpha|^{-3/2} \ \mathrm{d}\alpha.$$

However, as can be seen in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2128940/363087), this integral is $O(|k|^{-1})$, which, after squaring, is clearly not integrable over all $|k| \geqslant 1$ after switching to polar co-ordinates (obviously not including $0$ in the lower limit of the outer integral). We would need an estimate of at least $O(|k|^{-1 - \epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ to guarantee convergence of the outer integral.

One idea might be to try to bring the outer integral inside (though one would need to justify interchanging the order of integration). Using the asymptotics for the Bessel functions gives a product of cosines, and then one can use polar co-ordinates (taking $r = |\alpha|$). This would cancel out the $|\alpha|$ in the denominator, but then the $|k-\alpha|$ terms get very messy, which seems to make things worse. The Bessel functions appear to cause the most trouble. Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed?

One idea is to notice (as someone suggested in the comments) that the above is the $L^2$ norm of a convolution, and also that (up to a constant) we have

$$\displaystyle f(\xi) = \frac{J_{d/2}(|\xi|)}{|\xi|^{d/2}} = \mathcal{F}(\chi)(\xi),$$

where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. It can be shown that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and even $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for any $p \geqslant 2$. This lets us write the entire expression as

$$\|f \ast f\|_2^2 = \|\mathcal{F}(\chi) \ast \mathcal{F}(\chi)\|_2^2,$$

but unfortunately there is no kind of convolution theorem for functions on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ that I am aware of, without going into the theory of distributions. Moreover, $f$ does not even belong to $S(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for any $d$, so we cannot say much about the convolution. Thus, the problem is equivalent to asserting the finiteness of the above norm, $\|f \ast f\|_2$. If anyone has any ideas on how else the problem could be approached, then I would be very keen to hear about them.

Comment: I don't know if this can help but you may write your expression as an L_2 norm of a convolution.

Comment: @GGG It is interesting that you mention that, because that is mostly how this integral was derived -- it began as a discrete convolution which we then approximated by this integral. Roughly speaking this expression corresponds to the $L^4$ norm of the difference between the number of integer points inside a ball and its volume.

Comment: Interesting! I was mentioning that because when you have the norm of  a convolution, then you may use the Fourier transform. I'm not an expert of Bessel functions, so I don't know if their explicit Fourier transform is known.

Comment: Furthermore to give you some mathematical input: It looks like Cauchy-Schwarz could be very helpful here

Comment: @user363087 i saw you already reposted on MO, so forget about this comment

Comment: having a quick look the cauchy schwarz approach should yield (applying your inequality for bessel's functions) an upper bound for the inner integrals like $Const/(\rho^2|k|^4)$ which yield a finite value if integrated over $|k|\geq1$. Correct?

Comment: cool..that was much simpler then i thought in the beginning :-) 

for the other interval, the series expansion of the bessel function should do the job

Comment: @tired I just did the computation myself and I could only get $O(\rho^{-1}|k|^{-1})$ for each integral after applying Cauchy-Schwarz, giving $O(\rho^{-2}|k|^{-2})$ for the entire inner integral -- which is not enough for the outer integral to converge, unfortunately.

Comment: what a pity....

Comment: I believe some combinatorial decomposition is needed here, since $\frac{J_1(z)}{z}$ is not a Schwartz function, but behaves like a Schwartz function in a neighbourhood of the origin, and far from the origin we have a fairly good polynomial bound.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem can be tackled by bounding $\left|\frac{J_1(z)}{z}\right|$ with $\frac{1}{2}e^{-z^2/8}$ for $z\in[0,2\pi]$ and with $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z^3}}$ for $z\geq 2\pi$. [These bounds](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) come from the Taylor series at the origin and Laplace method. Let $f(z)=\frac{J_1(z)}{z}$ for simplicity. We have:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(\left|\alpha\right|)\,f(\left|k-\alpha\right|)\,d\mu\\ \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{\left|k-\alpha\right|\leq 2\pi}f(\left|\alpha\right|)\,e^{-|k-\alpha|^2/8}\,d\mu+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{\left|k-\alpha\right|\geq 2\pi}f(\left|\alpha\right|)\frac{d\mu}{|k-\alpha|^{3/2}}$$
and the original integral should be simple to approximate by splitting the integration range in four parts:

1. $\alpha$ and $k$ being close to each other and close to the origin;
2. $\alpha$ and $k$ being close to each other, far from origin;
3. $\alpha$ and $k$ being far from each other, both far from the origin;
4. $\alpha$ and $k$ being far from each other, one of them being close to the origin.

For instance, let we approximate
$$ I_1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{8}(\left|\alpha\right|^2+\left|k-\alpha\right|^2\right)\,d\alpha\right)^2\,dk .$$
By assuming $k=\rho_1(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)$ and switching to polar coordinates, the innermost integral equals
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\rho\,\exp\left(-\frac{1}{8}\left(2\rho^2+\rho_1^2-2\rho\rho_1\cos(\theta-\theta_1)\right)\right)\,d\rho\,d\theta $$
that is positive and bounded by
$$ 2\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{8}\left(2\rho^2-\rho_1^2-2\rho\rho_1\right)\right)\,d\rho\leq 16\pi \exp\left(-\frac{(\rho_1-4)^2}{8}\right) $$
that is a Schwartz function in $\rho_1$. It follows that $I_1$ is finite.

> On the other hand, most of the mass of the integral is concentrated on
>    the region over which
>    $\left|\alpha\right|,\left|k\right|,\left|\alpha-k\right|$ are large,
>    and by [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128908/computing-estimating-a-double-integral/2128940#2128940) (that ultimately boils down to the
>    triangle inequality) $I_3$ **is not** finite. *This is how the world
>    ends: not with a bang, but with a whimper.*

Comment: This looks very promising, but I have a few questions -- firstly, what do you mean when you write $\mathrm{d}\mu$? Secondly, since the inner integral is being squared, this seems to make it very difficult to then integrate the (square) of the two integrals you have bounded the inner integral by -- and despite partitioning the outer integral over $\mathbb{R}^d$ into 4 parts, I am not sure how we can deal with the squares of those integrals. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: @user363087: with $\mu$ I denoted the $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. I do not like to use $d\alpha$ since $\alpha$ is a vector, but that is just a matter of personal taste. About your second question: if $\alpha$ or $k-\alpha$ are small, a gaussian function, i.e. a Schwartz function appears in the integral. It follows that the only problematic case to deal with is the case in which both $\alpha$ and $k-\alpha$ are large. But in such a case we just have to approximate the integral of a rational function, and the exponent $\frac{3}{2}$ should be enough to grant convergence.

Comment: Apologies if this is a silly question, but I still can't see how to do any of the integrals. For instance, if $\alpha$ is small, then one of the integrals we deal with is $\displaystyle \int \left( \int e^{-(|\alpha|^2 + |k - \alpha|^2)/8} \ \mathrm{d}\alpha \right)^{2} \ \mathrm{d}k$. I have no idea how to do this. Could you by any chance show me how to do one of the cases so I can try to do the others?

Comment: @user363087: all right, updating.

Comment: Thanks. In the last line, how were you able to get rid of the factor of $\rho$ outside the exponential, and how was the inequality deduced?

Comment: @user363087: such integral depends on the error function, for which many tight approximations (through continued fractions, for instance) are known. Anyway, you may just apply Cauchy-Schwarz, and a worse approximation still is a Schwartz function.

Comment: Would this idea still work if we replaced the integrals over $\mathbb{R}^2$ with integrals over $\mathbb{R}^d$, $J_{1}$ with $J_{d/2}$, and $|\alpha|$, $|k-\alpha|$ with $|\alpha|^{d/2}$, $|k-\alpha|^{d/2}$? Is there a similar exponential bound for the quotient near the origin in that more general case?

Comment: Also, from your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2128940/363087), it seems that when both $|\alpha| \geqslant 2\pi$ and $|k-\alpha| \geqslant 2\pi$, the inner integral behaves like $O(|k|^{-1})$, which gives us an integral of $|k|^{-2}$... doesn't this diverge?

Comment: But then after switching to polar coordinates, the integral looks like $1/r$ -- doesn't this diverge when integrated over $[a, \infty)$ for some positive $a$?

Comment: @user363087: thinking twice about it, you (we?) are right. By my previous answer, case 3. is lethal.

Comment: That is a shame. I thought the integral had finally been solved. Regardless, thank you for putting so much effort into my problem and posting some interesting ideas.

Comment: @user363087: you're welcome.